# Rotate a small wheel using magnets

Tags: physics

I know this question already asked so much times.

I tried to rotate a wheel by placing few magnets on it. And I used some powerful magnet and repel it using opposite poles in the magnets placed in a wheel.

Thing is I got rotation for a while upto next magnet in the wheel. Only issue I get is the first magnet repels and make some movement in the wheel. When second magnet coming, it doesn't enter the repelling magnet position. Any idea to overcome this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about buildin a perpetual motion machine are better suited for http://physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the second magnet approaches the repelling magnet, move the repelling magnet away. When the second magnet reaches the original position of the first magnet, move the repelling magnet back into position, so as to push the second magnet on its way.

If you try to move the wheel *without* moving the repelling magnet, you may discover an important principle of physics.